# unable to install unity7 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

After upgrading ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, appearing to work with gnome, I can't find the way to install or activate unity 7. (working now with lightdm)
Could you please help? Thanks !

```
damien@earth:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for damien: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```